# Rewriting "If element has scrolled down past another element, do the following" from JQuery to vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Hello is it possible to rewrite the following JQuery snippet:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(".navigation").toggleClass("is-active", scroll >= $("example-div").offset().top);
});
$(window).scroll();
```

Into vanilla JS? I've tried everything, and searched through some other questions, to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: So `addEventListener("scroll", () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".navigation")).forEach(({ classList }) => classList.toggle("is-active", scroll >= theOtherElement.getBoundingClientRect().top + pageYOffset))); dispatchEvent(new Event("scroll"));`, whatever `theOtherElement` is (`$("example-div")` implies an `<example-div>` element).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) like this :

```js
const target = document.querySelector('#static');
const floating = document.querySelector('#floating');

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  ([entry]) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting)
      floating.innerText = 'Red is visible'
    else
      floating.innerText = 'Red is invisible'
  }, {
    threshold: 0
  }
);

observer.observe(target)
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0
}

main {
    height: 200vh;
}

#static {
    background-color: red;
}

#floating {
    position: fixed;
    left: 55px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#static,
#floating {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="floating">
  </div>
  
  <div id="static">
  </div>    
</main>
```

[compatibility link](https://caniuse.com/intersectionobserver)